# How to save the value of "textbox.Text" into a variable?

Tags: c#, textbox

I'd like to save the string value of "TextBox.Text" which I write into the TextBox into a variable with this Code.

```
public int Get_Value()

 if (value_textbox.Text=="")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No input");
        }

 string value_txt = value_textbox.Text;
 int value= int.Parse(value_txt);
 return value;
```

But "value.textbox.Text" has no value, only "". So, the Message Box is shown and I can't convert anything to int. If I use ".Lines" instead of ".Text" I have the same Problem.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: You should create [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This isn't valid C# as it stands and there's no info on how/when `Get_Value` is called.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow.
Your code seems fine, so the value of value_textbox is definitely ""
There is likely something else in your code that clears the textbox before you use 'Get_Value()'
Do you use the '.Clear()' method perhaps? Or set the text to equal "" before you call 'Get_Value()'?

We can't help without more code unfortunately, if you could edit your question to include more code, that'd be great.

Comment: What if the value in the textbox cannot be converted to a valid integer?  An **exception** will be thrown.  You are not handling this case...

Answer (score 0):

*return zero when textbox is empty.and when it is not try parsing it to Int.*

```
if (value_textbox.Text=="")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No input");
             return 0;
        }

int value= int.Parse(value_textbox.Text);
 return value;
```

*you can use terinary operator if you want it to be concise:*

```
return String.IsNUllOrEmpty(value_textbox.Text)?0:int.Parse(value_textbox.Text)
```